# Express - Give a base path to res.redirect()

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm not sure if this issue is something that can easily be fixed but here's the scenario. Say we have an express `app()` with a separate `router()`.

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

const router = express.Router()

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.redirect('/bar')
})

app.use('/foo', router)

app.listen('8000')
```

Say we send a request to `http://localhost:8000/foo/`. I need the `res.redirect('/bar')` to redirect to `http://localhost:8000/foo/bar` instead of redirecting to `http://localhost:8000/bar`. The only key component here is that we cannot use redirects that are relative to the current route, so `res.redirect('bar')` would not be suitable for us.

Is there any way that we can override `res.redirect()`'s functionality to prepend `/foo` to every redirect? Also, I cannot modify every `res.redirect()` with `req.originalUrl` or anything similar.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Seen as your route is attached to `/foo`, just doing `redirect('bar')` without the slash should give you a relative url or `/foo/bar`.

Comment: Unfortunately we can't use relative paths live that

Comment: You could maybe place a middleware before your gets, to create a redirect wrapper function..  `function (req, res, next) { var oredirect = res.redirect.bind(res); res.redirect = (url) => oredirect('/foo' + url); next(); }` or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

Figured out how to do it with middleware -

```js
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  const redirector = res.redirect
  res.redirect = function (url) {
    url = '/foo' + url
    redirector.call(this, url)
  }
  next()
})
```